# shell script getopts options validations

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell-script, bash-scripting

I'm trying to check if all the validations are true and work but my logic I think is not correct and I'm new to coding. So I initialized p=0 and un=0, when user passes both option it should give error. Second validation user has to choose only one option either -p or -u either one,third validation if user doesnt pass any option and i know there should be more validations I think I just don't know.

```
p=0   # initialize variables
un=0
file=””

  while getopts "d:uph" option; do
          case $option in
           d)
               file=$OPTARG
               ;;
           u)
               un=1
               ;;
               
           p)
               p=1
               ;;
                
           h)
                help
                exit ;;

           *)  echo "Error: Invalid option"
                exit;;
        esac
  done

#Validations
# This is my first logic validation 
if [ "$p" ] || [ "$un" ];then
         echo "must provide -u or -p" 1>&2 ;
         Help
         exit 3 ;
        fi
#Second one, i want check make sure they not passing both options

if (( p && u ));then
echo "must not pass  two options";
Help
exit 3
```

Comment: you could just check to see if p is not equal to un. if both are 1 then they provided the wrong number of arguments, if both a zero, they didn't provide any arguments, and only if the two are different ( {p=1, u=0}, {p=0, u=1}) would be valid. so one if statement to test if they are equal, and an if statement inside it, that will test if p = 1. if it is, then print the "only one arg" message, and if p=0, then print the "must provide an arg" message.

Comment: `[ "$p" ]` tests to see if the value of `p` is a non-null string. Neither "0" nor "1" is the null string, so that's always going to be true. You probably want `[ "$p" = 0 ]` or `[ "$p" = 1 ]`, or maybe `(( p ))` (since that last one's an arithmetic context, it treats 0 as false and 1 as true). Actually, `if ! (( p || q ))` would work for the first test.

Answer (score 1):

You could check that one *and only one* option has been provided by adding their values, and checking that the sum is 1 (not 0 or 2).

This will do that in one line:

```
test $(( p + un )) -eq 1 || echo "Error: one or the other, not both!"
```